# Cita famosa de Ana María Campos

Tags: significado, coloquialismos, citas

Estaba leyendo sobre Ana María Campos ayer. Quiero aprender qué estaba ella diciendo cuando dijo

> Si no capitula, monda.

Estoy todavía aprendiendo español, y tengo mucha curiosidad por el significado de esta frase.

Comment: Mira: "[si usted no capitula, monda”; queriendo significar para la época que si no capitulaba tendría que enfrentarse a las consecuencias](http://digaloahidigital.com/articulo/si-usted-no-capitula-monda)" y también "[a valiente mujer zuliana Ana María Campos, refiriéndose al realista Morales. Con ello quiso decir : Si no se rinde, se acaba.](http://www.noticierodigital.com/2014/11/si-no-capitula-monda/)". Esa es la explicación de lo que significa. El uso de "monda" (o mondar) entiendo que el el quid de esta pregunta.

Comment: @Rob, mi respuesta tiene otra posibilidad.

Answer (score 1):

He estado leyendo la entrada de la Wikipedia dedicada a [Ana María Campos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ana_Mar%C3%ADa_Campos), la cual parece estar principalmente basada en esta [página web](http://www.minmujer.gob.ve/?q=noticias/ana-mar%C3%ADa-campos-hero%C3%ADna-en-la-guerra-de-independencia-de-venezuela)

> "Si Morales no capitula, monda" – que en el lenguaje vernáculo de
>   aquellos tiempos quería decir: Si no se rinde, muere.

La relación entre monda y muerte quizás podamos rastrearla en el D.R.A.E, si tenemos en cuenta que

[**monda**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PcfyMjb%7CPch8aEr)

> 1. f. Acción y efecto de mondar.

[**mondar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pcz21mF)

> 7. tr. coloq. Azotar, apalear.

---

Las explicaciones que aparecen en los enlaces aportados por @Diego en los comentarios

> 1. Si no capitula tendrá que enfrentarse a las consecuencias

Se corresponde con la interpretación "si no se rinde, muere (apalizado)"

> 2. Si no se rinde, se acaba

Ésta no la entiendo. Si no se rinde, ¿qué se acaba?, ¿cómo se acaba?

En todos los casos me parece un poco aventurado por parte de una conspiradora omitir todas las condiciones para que muera el mariscal [Francisco Tomás Morales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Tom%C3%A1s_Morales).
La frase completa y más correcta sería

> Si no capitula, continuaremos la lucha y cuando venzamos, lo ajusticiaremos.

Nótese que todo nacionalismo construye sus héroes y sus mitos, cualquiera sabe lo que dijo o no realmente Ana María Castillo. Lo que sí parece claro es que no se cumplió su amenaza, pues Tomás Morales murió muchos años despues tranquilamente en las Islas Canarias.

Answer (score 0):

Podría haber otras explicaciones, pero según lo que yo he podido encontrar significa "Si no está rindiendo, está venciendo."  El verbo "capitular" significar rendir o dejar conquistar, mientras que el verbo "[mondar](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/mondar)" significa conquistar o derrotar.  Es parecido a la expresión en inglés, "La mejor posición defensiva es una posición ofensiva."

Comment: Mira la sección de [answer] para revisar lo que se espera de las respuestas. Deberías explicar un poco por qué crees que significa eso. Así como está ahora es casi un comentario, y una afirmación que no se puede validar. Es decir, como puedo estar seguro de que significa eso y no lo contrario, u ora cosa distinta?

Comment: Si esto es mejor, favor de quitar los menos.

Comment: I knew "[capitular](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7Ksw8ql|7KtmlfI)" and its meaning, but I didn't know that meaning of "mondar". It is not among the [meanings listed by DRAE for "mondar"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pcz21mF) . Where did you see it. Could you please add those references?

Comment: Mondar looks like a regional word.  I found it in Google translate. It has various meanings, but within the context this seems to be the most logical.

Comment: I added a link to the word mondar. within Google Translate.